# Getting an SQLite error using this code but it works in another file

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Everytime this runs it says the table *streamers* doesn't exist even though IK it does. This code I am using works in another file for another script and now it doesnt work... any help? What it does is it checks the API entry from Beam.pro and compares the streamers online status with the status that is saved in the database, and it doesnt work if the database cant be checked because it cant be found.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const request = require('request');
const sql = require('sqlite');
sql.open('./streamers.sqlite');
let Config;

//look for config
try {
    Config = require('./config.json');
} catch(e) {
    console.log('Please create an config.json file in the main directory based off of the config.json.example file!\n' + e.stack);
    process.exit();
}

console.log('I am ready for work :)')

const bot = new Discord.Client()

function check() {
    for(let i = 0; Config.streamers.length > i; i++) {
         sql.get(`SELECT * FROM streamers WHERE streamer ='${Config.streamers[i]}'`).then(row => {
            if (!row) {
                sql.run('INSERT INTO streamers (streamer, status) VALUES (?, ?)', [Config.streamers[i], false]);
             } else {
                 request('https://beam.pro/api/v1/channels/'+Config.streamers[i],
                    function(err,res,body){
                        const data = JSON.parse(body);
                        if(!data) console.log(`The channel, ${Config.streamers[i]}, is not a valid beam.pro channel!`);
                        if(data.online === false && row.status == true) {
                            sql.run(`UPDATE streamers SET status = false WHERE streamer = ${Config.streamers[i]}`);
                            console.log(`${Config.streamers[i]} is offline!`)
                        };
                        if(streamers[i].online === true && data.online == true) return;
                        if(data.online === true && row.status == false) {
                            sql.run(`UPDATE streamers SET status = true WHERE streamer = ${Config.streamers[i]}`);
                            for(let j = 0; j < Config.channelID.length; j++){
                                const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                                    .setTitle('Beam Alerts')
                                    .setDescription(`${Congif.streamers[i]} is now live!`)
                                    .addField(`Playing For:`, `${data.numFollowers} followers`,true)
                                    .addField(`${Config.streamers[i]} is Playing:`, '${data.type.name}',true)
                                    .setFooter('BaconHawk - NITEHAWK')
                                    .setColor([0,45,255])
                                    .setTimestamp()
                                bot.channels[Config.channelID[j]].sendEmbed(embed);
                            }
                        }
                    });
    }    
})
    }

}

bot.on('ready', () => setInterval(check, 60*5*1000));
bot.login(Config.bot_token)
```

Comment: You have a relative path for the location of the sqlite file. Is the location of the sqlite file correct given the location of the other JS file?

Comment: @DanielT. it is in the same directory as the bot.js file

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? What have you tried?

Comment: @DanielT. Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 14): Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no
such table: streamers

Comment: That is the error

Comment: And I have tried recreating the file multiple times

Comment: What line is it failing on? It looks like the error is that it can find the sqlite file, but you're trying to do an insert on a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: @DanielT. It isnt giving me a line, but I have checked them all many times

Comment: Does the table exist in the SQLite file?

Comment: @DanielT. as far as I know I shouldn't need to make one... my other code doesn't make a table and it works 100% fine

Comment: Then you'll have to show us the other code.

Comment: @DanielT. This is the other code that works fine... It is a for a different task, but it is the same exact formatting... any clue?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/okikixuqej.coffeescript

Comment: Ignore the .coffeescript... hastebin is dumb